# Is there a way to quickly create a new dataframe by multiplying one column of an existing dataframe to the rest of the columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (assuming I have many more columns):

```
   m a b
t1 1 1 2
t2 2 1 2
t3 3 1 2
```

I would like to multiply column `m` to column `a` and `b` element by element and return the following dataframe:

```
   a b
t1 1 2
t2 2 4
t3 3 6
```

Currently I convert column `m` into a vector first. Just wonder if anyone has a more direct way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

If need multiple only `a` and `b` columns by `m`:

```
print (df[['a','b']].mul(df.m, axis=0))
    a  b
t1  1  2
t2  2  4
t3  3  6
```

If column `m` is first you can select all columns without first by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then multiple:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1:])
    a  b
t1  1  2
t2  1  2
t3  1  2

df = df.iloc[:, 1:].mul(df.m, axis=0)
print (df)
    a  b
t1  1  2
t2  2  4
t3  3  6
```

More generally is filter columns which are not `m` by list comprehension:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col !='m']
print (cols)
['a', 'b']

df = df[cols].mul(df.m, axis=0)
print (df)
    a  b
t1  1  2
t2  2  4
t3  3  6
```

**Timings**:

```
#[300000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [438]: %timeit (df[['a','b']].mul(df.m, axis=0))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.41 ms per loop

In [439]: %timeit (df.iloc[:, 1:].mul(df.m, axis=0))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.66 ms per loop

In [440]: %timeit (df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: x*df.m))
100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Similarly, and perhaps easier to see how to generalize to other operations, `df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: x*df.m)`

Comment: Ya, but apply is very slow.

Comment: @vmg - I add timings, it is slowier, but testing is only in two columns.